# Trouble with storing a position in a variable in turtle (python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Code

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()
def reset(p):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(p);
    pen.forward(30);
    pen.down();
    pen.forward(100);
def cdraw():
   p = pen.position();
   for x in range(180):
      pen.backward(1)
      pen.right(1)
  return p;
  reset
```

My reset function seems to not be working, I think the problem is with my goto(p) line. I am not sure if I am allowed to use:

```
 p = pen.position();
```

My code currently runs cdraw function and then stops.

Comment: you don't need `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last question involved parentheses that should not have been included:

```
turtle.onscreenclick(star()) -> turtle.onscreenclick(star)
```

This one is the reverse, missing parentheses that are needed:

```
reset -> reset()
```

But there are other problems -- parentheses or not, any code directly following a `return` statement will never be reached:

```
return p;
reset  # never reached
```

The snippet of code you provide never calls `cdraw()` so `reset()` will never be called.  Finally, semicolons really don't have a place in a properly written Python program.

Below is my best guess at what your program was intended to look like, but there's not enough information to know for sure:

```
import turtle

def reset(p):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(p)
    pen.forward(30)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(100)

def cdraw():
    p = pen.position()
    for x in range(180):
        pen.backward(1)
        pen.right(1)
    reset(p)

window = turtle.Screen()

pen = turtle.Turtle()

cdraw()

window.exitonclick()
```

These questions are not about turtle graphics but instead about basic Python programming.

Comment: Thanks! I know it was a very silly mistakes thank you

Answer (score 0):

First: you don't need `;`

Second: to run function you need function name and `()` - ie. `reset()` - you have `reset`

Third: `return` ends function (returns to place where function was called) and everything after `return` will not be executed.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def reset(p):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(p);
    pen.forward(30);
    pen.down();
    pen.forward(100);

def cdraw():
    p = pen.position();
    for x in range(180):
      pen.backward(1)
      pen.right(1)
    # call function `reset` with `p`
    reset(p)

# --- main ---

window = turtle.Screen()

pen = turtle.Turtle()

cdraw()
```

Comment: I did not know that after return, nothing else will be processed. I know about the semicolons but I heard it was good practice for other languages as it is required in many other languages. Thanks!